# Securing an Angular/Go Google App Engine application

Tags: angularjs, security, google-app-engine, go

I have a Go app that uses Angular for the frontend.
The Go app is the backend, and is used to handle rest requests.
Angular will make service requests to Go to get data, save data, etc.

I have the app deployed as a Go app on GAE, so I thought I would use some Google service to secure the app.
I do not know how to secure the application.
I want to secure the entire app, and have different areas of the app require different user roles.
For instance, I want an 'admin' area, a 'view only' area, etc.

I have the app deployed on GAE and it works fine, I now just need to add the security pieces.
I am confused if I need to reference how to secure Go or Angular apps on GAE, since it is sort of both; however, my app.yaml uses "api_version: go1"

In case it matters, my file layout is:

```
fooProject
    |
    src (where app.yaml is)
     |
     frontend (where my angular files are)
     |   |
     |   app 
     |   |
     |   partials
     github.com
         |
         me(where my go files are)
         |
         gorilla (using gorilla for some Go stuff)
```

A snippet of app.yaml:

```
application: fooproject
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:

  - url: /_ah/remote_api
  script: _go_app
  login: admin

  - url: /rest/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: unauthorized

 - url: /
  static_files: frontend/index.html
  upload: frontend/index.html
  login: required
  mime_type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Snippet of app.js:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            controller:EntryCtrl,
            templateUrl:'frontend/partials/entry.html'
        }).
        when('/admin/carList', {
            controller:ListCtrl,
            templateUrl:'frontend/partials/admin/car-list.html'
        }).
```

What confuses me is, is Go or Angular controlling the URLs?
Angular has the URL mapping, but Go has app.yaml defining URLs too.
I do not know how to think of these two items together while figuring out how to secure the app.
Any push in a direction?

Comment: Angular has no more power to control your app's server than jQuery does--it's just JavaScript. Security all has to happen in Go (or the limited `app.yaml` options you've already deployed). https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/ documents GAE's user APIs, which you can use in your Go code to deny access as needed. We probably can't give you much more detailed help without knowing how your Go code is structured (like, have you written handlers for Angular to use for accessing data, or is some tool doing that for you, or...?).

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to display/not display links on an Angular page based on a user's role? It seems better to not display a link if a particular is not allowed to use the link, than to display a link that a user may not actually use?

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about Angular/GAE. All I can suggest is looking at Angular docs for how to work out the client side, and GAE docs like https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/ for anything you need to work out on the server side.